# Mac OS calendar does not tell me about "proposed new time" responses from gmail

Tags: calendar, ical, google-calendar

I use my MacOS calendar to show me appointments from my various calendars. It stays nicely in sync with my google calendar with one exception: it does not tell me about proposed new time responses to my meeting invitations. I have to go into my gmail or google calendar to see those messages and accept them.

This has been the case in various versions of MacOS up to and including Ventura. How can I change this?

For context I use the MacOS calendar because it syncs nicely across desktop and mobile, and it gives me notifications. I haven't reliably been able to get notifications from safari when my google calendar tab is closed, even though I have said that I do want notifications for the calendar and safari.